# v-for with duplicate keys in object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, v-for

I receive a response from a JSON API which contains the object `locations` each location has the same key, `label`. When I try to use a `v-for` loop I am unable to print out more than one of the locations. What is going on?

**Response from API call**

```
"locations": [
    {
      "label": "Brighton",
      "label": "London",
      "label": "Manchester",
    }
  ],
```

**Template**

```
<span v-for="(item, index) in locations" :key="index">
    <span v-if="index != 0">, </span>
    <span> {{ item.label }} </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Because, you have one element in locations array. When you ar using `v-for`, `for` is looking for array element. So `if` takes one element.

Comment: What is the correct way of doing it? @Musulmon

Comment: The best way is to change the server-side if you can. There is an another to convert JSON to array. `{
      "label": "Brighton",
      "label": "London",
      "label": "Manchester",
    }` to `[
      "label": "Brighton",
      "label": "London",
      "label": "Manchester",
    ]`

Comment: Try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array) to convert to array.

Comment: @Simon In JavaScript, such an object with only duplicate keys would be evaluated as an object that has only one key, where the last value wins. If the API provides the data as a string, you'll have to use a custom parser (other than `JSON.parse()`).

Comment: Same parameter name is causing the issue. The last one is replacing the others, as musulmon said, it is the most suitable format.